# Loop over constexpr array

Tags: c++, for-loop, constexpr

I have the following files:

**test.hpp**

```
class Test {
    static constexpr const char* array[] {
        "hello",
        "world",
        "!"
    };
  public:   
    void do_stuff();
    
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
void Test::do_stuff() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::cout << array[i];
  }
}

int main() {
  Test object;
  object.do_stuff();

}
```

This fails with the following linking error:

> undefined reference to `Test::array'

So how can I define a constexpr array and then iterate over it?

Comment: If you use `c++`, prefer `std::array` over old-c arrays.

Comment: This should link just fine - what compiler are you using? And which language standard do you assume, do you pass a `-std=c++??`  argument?

Comment: look here: https://godbolt.org/z/9abK4h same error, it is gone when you specify `--std=c++17`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` members need an offline declaration or explicit `inline`:

From C++17:

```
inline static constexpr const char* array[] {
```

Other solution:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
    static constexpr const char* array[] {
        "hello",
        "world",
        "!"
    };
  public:   
    void do_stuff();
    
};

constexpr char* Test::array[];

void Test::do_stuff() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::cout << array[i];
  }
}

int main() {
  Test object;
  object.do_stuff();

}
```

Comment: You want `static constexpr char const* array` and not `static constexpr char* array`. The `constexpr` is for the array but the `const` (which OP has but you have removed) is for the pointer _to constness_. You currently have a constexpr array of pointers that may mutate what they point to.

Comment: added back the const

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `std::array` instead of a raw array:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    static constexpr std::array<const char*, 2> arr{"hello", "world"};
};

// Out-of class definition.
const std::array<const char*, 2> Test::arr;

int main() {
    for (const auto c : Test::arr) { std::cout << c << " "; }
    // hello world
}
```

note the out-of-class definition needed if the `arr` static data member is ODR-used.

Comment: Why, range-based `for` works for built-in arrays just as well.

Comment: The "2" needed there ruins std::array a bit, IMHO. The moment I caught myself counting the items, I reverted use of std::array like that.